# Selenium/Python - How to click onclick() button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to find and click with selenium on python a little plus-button but for any reason I a get a `TypeError`

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

This is the link https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/treeView and I try to find and click the following codesnippet from the html.

```html
<i id="plus_Anatomy" onclick="openTree(this)" class="fa fa-plus-circle treeCollapseExpand fakeLink"></i>
```

This is my python code so far. At first it looks like everything should work. So browser windows opens and the webpage is loaded, but then I get this error mentioned above.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/treeView")
plus = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME('fakeLink'))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", plus)
```

The bigger goal is to click on all the buttons and scrap the complete html in the end.
can anybody please help me? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error.
Instead of

```py
plus = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME('fakeLink'))
```

Try

```py
plus = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'fakeLink')
```

Or even

```py
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'fakeLink').click()
```